# Does css `calc()` function support `fr` unit?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

As the title of the question suggests, does CSS `calc()` function support `fr` unit as used in the following example?

```
.sample-grid {
    --main-fr: 60fr;
    grid-template-columns: var(--main-fr) 1rem calc(100 - var(--main-fr));
}
```

My initial guess is it doesn't - neither in Firefox nor Chrome.

Comment: The example in the question seems to think of `fr` unit like percentage (which it's not), probably a good sign to approach the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, according to [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)

> 7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the 'fr' unit
>
> A flexible length or <flex> is a dimension with the *'fr'* unit, which represents a fraction of the leftover space in the grid container. Tracks sized with `fr` units are called flexible tracks
>   as they flex in response to leftover space similar to how flex items fill space in a flex container.
>
> > Note: <flex> values are not <length>s (nor are they compatible with <length>s, like some <percentage> values), **so they cannot be represented in or combined with other unit types in 'calc()' expressions**.

<sup>emphasize mine</sup>